# Render labels in circular path in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

Render labels in circular path and aligned center to the width of the arc,

Intially, i have tried by point on the circle formula to position the label as below,

```
       label_X_Position = (float) (centreX)  - (labelRadius ) * Math.sin(angleForLabel));
       label_Y_Position = (float) ((centreY) + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(angleForLabel));
       canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(labelText), (float) label_X_Position, (float) label_Y_Position, paint);
```

but when the length of the label value increased it doesn't looks like circular path. For better understanding i have attached a diagramatic representation for my requirment,

[image]

in the above image, while placing the value `100000` as per existing implementation, the text value will start from the arc. I need that to be shared based on its length.

[image]